# MachineConfig when training Model with TPU on GCP with Tensorflow-cloud

Tags: tensorflow, google-cloud-platform, cloud

I am trying to train a rather large model (Longformer-large with a CNN classification head on top) on Google Cloud Platform. I am using Tensorflow-cloud and Colab to run my model. I tried to run this with batchsize 4 and 4 P100-GPUs but I still get an OOM error, so I would like to try it with TPU. I have increased batch size to 8 now.

However, I get the error that TPU config cannot be the chief_worker_config.

This is my code:

```
tfc.run(
distribution_strategy="auto",
requirements_txt="requirements.txt",
docker_config=tfc.DockerConfig(
   image_build_bucket=GCS_BUCKET
),
worker_count=1,
worker_config= tfc.COMMON_MACHINE_CONFIGS["TPU"],
chief_config=tfc.COMMON_MACHINE_CONFIGS["TPU"],
job_labels={"job": JOB_NAME})
```

This is the error:

```
Validating environment and input parameters.
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-26-e1be60d71623> in <module>()
     19     worker_config= tfc.COMMON_MACHINE_CONFIGS["TPU"],
     20     chief_config=tfc.COMMON_MACHINE_CONFIGS["TPU"],
---> 21     job_labels={"job": JOB_NAME},
     22 )

2 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow_cloud/core/run.py in run(entry_point, requirements_txt, docker_config, distribution_strategy, chief_config, worker_config, worker_count, entry_point_args, stream_logs, job_labels, service_account, **kwargs)
    256         job_labels=job_labels or {},
    257         service_account=service_account,
--> 258         docker_parent_image=docker_config.parent_image,
    259     )
    260     print("Validation was successful.")

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow_cloud/core/validate.py in validate(entry_point, requirements_txt, distribution_strategy, chief_config, worker_config, worker_count, entry_point_args, stream_logs, docker_image_build_bucket, called_from_notebook, job_labels, service_account, docker_parent_image)
     78     _validate_distribution_strategy(distribution_strategy)
     79     _validate_cluster_config(
---> 80         chief_config, worker_count, worker_config, docker_parent_image
     81     )
     82     _validate_job_labels(job_labels or {})

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow_cloud/core/validate.py in _validate_cluster_config(chief_config, worker_count, worker_config, docker_parent_image)
    160             "Invalid `chief_config` input. "
    161             "`chief_config` cannot be a TPU config. "
--> 162             "Received {}.".format(chief_config)
    163         )
    164 

ValueError: Invalid `chief_config` input. `chief_config` cannot be a TPU config. Received <tensorflow_cloud.core.machine_config.MachineConfig object at 0x7f5860afe210>.
```

Can someone tell me how I can run my code on GCP-TPUs? I actually don't care too much about time, I just want some configuration that runs without getting OOM issues (so GPU if it works totally fine with me as well).

Thank you!

Comment: Hi @JanGe, You can check this [document](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/tpu#tpu_initialization) for TPU initialization. Let me know if it’s helpful or not?

Comment: Hi @JanGe, Is the above comment helpful?